# Higgs self-coupling

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, higgs, interactions

The measurement of the Higgs particle mass at the LHC has made the determination of the value of the Higgs self-coupling possible: with $M_H \approx 125$ GeV, one gets $\lambda \approx 1/8$.

Does this particular value imply anything special for the Standard Model, except that now books can be filled with the values of $M_H$ and $\lambda$?

Comment: Perhaps this is helpful - I am not really sure. The self-coupling constant determines how likely it is that a Higgs Boson can decay into 2 Higgs Bosons? This video shows how that could be important. [The Higgs Mass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjCypYnBYwQ). It is rather old - from 2014.

Comment: You said it: SM reviews and the PDG can state measured facts. No magic, if someone duped you into expecting such.

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. Should we see this low value of $\lambda$ as a way to say that it will be hard to actually observe cubic and quartic Higgs interactions?

Comment: No, it is not dramatically small. Observations are  [all but schedule-ready](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-08595-3) .

Answer (score 2):

> Does this particular value imply anything special for the Standard Model, except that now books can be filled with the values of MH and λ?

The standard model is an ongoing model fitting  current at the time experimental data. It has been continuously updated since its inception when new data invalidate it. So, from  Cosmas Zachos' [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140%2Fepjc%2Fs10052-020-08595-3) a diagram like this

[image: higgsλ]

needs very high energy experiments, in order for two on mass Higgs to appear from a virtual one,  the mass of the Higgs being so large. Such experiments in addition to refining the value of $λ$ will also:

> Higgs pair production provides a unique handle for measuring the strength of the Higgs self interaction and *constraining the shape* of the Higgs potential.

Physics history shows that when the energy of experiments is increased, new and unexpected phenomena can also appear, so the future will tell how useful $λ$ is.

Comment: ...and a +1 for 200k! Congratulations!

Comment: @NiharKarve  thanks, age tells :), I am a member for 10 years